# String formatting in scala - maximum decimal precision

Tags: scala

`"%.3f".format(1)` returns `1.000`.
`"%.3f".format(4.0/3.0)` returns `1.333`.

Is there some easy way to have these return `1` and `1.333`? I thought the standard `printf` format specified that precision as the maximum already, but apparently not in Scala.

Comment: Scala just uses normal Java formatting, so the question isn't really Scala-specific. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html for full description of formatting strings.

Comment: `"%.3f".format (1)` does not return 1.000, but fails. `"%.3f".format (1.0)` or 1f is needed. Else you get a `java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.Integer`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The default formatter used by printf seems to be a generic one that doesn't have all the same support than `[DecimalFormat][1]`. You can instantiate a custom formatter along those lines:

```
scala> import java.text.DecimalFormat 
import java.text.DecimalFormat

scala> val formatter = new DecimalFormat("#.###")
formatter: java.text.DecimalFormat = java.text.DecimalFormat@674dc

scala> formatter.format(1)
res36: java.lang.String = 1

scala> formatter.format(1.34)
res37: java.lang.String = 1.34

scala> formatter.format(4.toFloat / 3)
res38: java.lang.String = 1.333

scala> formatter.format(1.toFloat)
res39: java.lang.String = 1
```

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html for more information.

Answer (score 7):

`"%.3f".format(1)` will throw an `java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException` because of the wrong type (`Float` is expected and you give a `Int`).

Even if you use `"%.3f".format(1.0)`, you will get `1.000`.

You can use a method like the following to obtain the expected result :

```
def format(x:AnyVal):String = x match {
  case x:Int => "%d".format(x)
  case x:Long => "%d".format(x)
  case x:Float => "%.3f".format(x)
  case x:Double => "%.3f".format(x)
  case _ => ""
}
```

This method will return the expected format based on argument type.

Comment: This still returns "1.000" for 1.0f

Answer (score 0):

How about simply getting rid of the zeroes after formatting?

```
scala> Array(1.0,1.10,1.110).map("%.3g" format _).map(_.replaceAll("[.0]*$",""))
res7: Array[java.lang.String] = Array(1, 1.1, 1.11)
```

Comment: Careful with this, as it uses the locale to pick what to use as the decimal-point. And it might be a ',' and not a '.'